# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to yaws file?

Tags: ajax, erlang, cors, yaws, erlangweb

I send a post request to YAWS server using AJAX from a different port/domain but javascript returns this error message:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.yaws. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Now I understand that I need to include CORS headers in **index.yaws** file but I don't know how to do it in `Erlang`.

Comment: How is your `index.yaws` file returning its results?

Comment: out(Arg)-> {html, string}. string is json encoded line which should return some mysql data.

Comment: Thanks. Next question: is there some particular set of origins you want to allow? Or is it just `localhost`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set only `localhost` as an allowed origin you could try the code below. Note that it represents the JSON results you currently return with the variable `YourJsonString`.

```
out(Arg) ->
    Hdrs = yaws_api:arg_headers(Arg),
    case yaws_api:get_header(Hdrs, "Origin") of
        "localhost" ->
            [{header, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost"}},
             {html, YourJsonString}];
        _ ->
            {html, YourJsonString}
    end.
```

Comment: you are the programmer, Thanks!